# How do I set a dymanic class value?

Tags: haml

I have the following `html.erb` code that I'm looking to move to Haml:

```
<span class="<%= item.dashboardstatus.cssclass %>" >

<%= item.dashboardstatus.status %>

</span>
```

What does it associate the CSS class of the currently assigned status to the span?

How is this done in Haml? I'm sure I'm missing something really simple.

Edit: Gah. I can't believe I didn't figure that out on my own. Just goes to show that two sets of eyes are better than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an equivalent code in HAML:

```
%span.{#item.dashboardstatus.cssclass}
     = item.dashboardstatus.status
```

There are two tools available for conversion of HTML to HAML:

1) `html2haml` tool for terminal application

2) Online tool: http://html2haml.heroku.com/